# Why when try to using Place Autocomplete for iOS in Google API just get 5 results not more?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am following this sample code from **google api**:

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete

but get just **5** result.
How to increase my results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information from https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_responses

A JSON response contains two root elements:

status contains metadata on the request. See Status Codes below.
predictions contains an array of places, with information about the place. See Place Autocomplete Results for information about these results. The Google Places API Web Service returns up to **5** results

**Google Places API returns up to 5 results only**

Comment: Unfortunately it's need IP for website. But i wanna using it in iOS app.